# What cannot stand outside a door?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

Let there be a house of which there is a beautified front door that is closed. Now: what is that "thing" for which it is impossible, logically (and ***irrefutably***), to be outside this closed door?

Comment: The door, the house, a square circle...

Comment: My irrational friend, it is very much possible to construct another house (a small one it may be, with a lesser height) outside the door of the house mentioned. It is logically possible, that is what I say. And the answer to the question, is of such a kind that it is impossible, very much impossible, logically, to be outside the door.

Comment: @Kalis: he did not say "a door", he said "*the* door". Your puzzle has too many answers.

Comment: @Kalis Welcome to PSE. As you have noticed, questions of this nature tend to come under high levels of scrutiny. It is very difficult to create such a question that truly only has one answer. As such, most of these questions are closed as being too broad. I would suggest adding limiting clues/suggestions in order to try and limit the possible answers and thus allow your question to be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna go with...

> The inside

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many answers, but here:

> The threshold